# Explaining Conditional Probability and the Urn problem with white and black balls

Tags: probability

I am trying to interpret the meaning behind the conditional probabilities when setting up the problem. Can someone confirm with me if I am understanding the problem correctly?

Problem Statement:
There are n-number of urns, each with "a" white balls and "b" black balls. One ball is chosen at random from urn 1 and placed into urn 2. Then one ball is chosen at random from urn 2 and moved into urn 3. This is done until the very last nth urn. What is the probability that the ball chosen from the nth urn is white?

I am solving this with conditional probability.

For my notation, P(Ai) is the probability of choosing a white ball from the ith urn, i.e., P(A1) is the probability of choosing a white ball from the 1st urn. P(Ai*) is complement, or not chosing a white ball from the ith urn. P(A) is the generic probability of choosing a white ball.

P(A1) = a/(a+b)

P(A2) = P(A|A1)P(A1) + P(A|A1*)P(A1*)

What does this P(A2) equation mean in words? I am trying to understand how this equation applies to this problem.

My best guess is that there are two possibilities that result in a white ball taken from urn 2:

- (1) A white ball is chosen from urn 2 AND a white ball came from urn 1, OR
- (2) A white ball is chosen from urn 2 AND a white ball did not come from urn 1.

(1) can be written in set theory is P(A and A1)

(2) can be written in set theory as P(A and A1*)

The problem is setup as the union of these two possibilities.

P(A2) = P(A and A1) or P(A and A1*)

These possibilities are mutually exclusive, meaning a white ball either came from urn 1 or one did not. So the union turns into addition:

P(A2) = P(A and A1) + P(A and A1*)

Intersection is equal to conditional probability by: P(A and A1) = P(A|A1)P(A1)

So putting it all together: P(A2) = P(A|A1)P(A1) + P(A|A1*)P(A1*)

At the nth urn, P(An) = P(A|An-1)P(An-1) + P(A|An-1*)P(An-1*)

Is my understanding correct? Or am I mistaken? That is my best guess at explaining the problem and equation into words.

Comment: If I have interpreted your posting correctly, you nailed it.

Comment: Your approach is correct.  If you work out $\Pr(A_2)$ explicitly, you should be able to infer what $\Pr(A_n)$ is.  You can prove your result by induction.